# Rails undefined method `category' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am having a very strange problem, I have this file for User#show view:

```
%h1 My Appliances
.floatright= link_to "Add appliance", new_appliance_profile_path
%table
  %tr
    %th Category
    %th Manufacturer
    %th Model
    %th Room
    %th Hours On
    %th Hours Sleeping
    %th
  - @user.appliance_profiles.each do |ap|
    %tr{:class => cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even')}
      %td= ap.appliance.category
      %td= ap.appliance.manufacturer
      %td= ap.appliance.model
      %td= ap.room.name
      %td= ap.hours_on
      %td= ap.hours_sleep
      %td= link_to "edit", edit_appliance_profile_path(ap)
```

and receive the error: `undefined method 'category' for nil:NilClass`

My model does have a category string attribute. What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that in this call:

```
%td= ap.appliance.category
```

`appliance` is `nil`. If it's OK that not all `appliance_profiles` have an `appliance`, you can do this:

```
%td= ap.appliance.try(:category)
```

If all the `appliance_profiles` *should have* an `appliance`, you have to check your database for missing data.

Answer (score 2):

in `ap.appliance.category`,  `ap.appliance` is nil

You can try to initialize it/print based on if its nil or not

Answer (score 2):

The error means that the variable on which the "category" method is being invoked is nil. In this case the line is

```
%td= ap.appliance.category
```

So it follows that `ap.appliance` resolves to nil. Why, I cannot tell given the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

It could possibly mean that one of your actions is not saving the record, thus returning nil.  Check your console.